# SQL Query Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
name        week    effort
quentin     1       1
quentin     1       2
quentin     2       1
tracy       1       1       
joe         2       2
```

There will only be a handful of unique names so it doesn't need to be dynamic

And I would like to query it to return something like

```
week    QuentinEffortSum    TracyEffortSum  JoeEffortSum
1       3                   1               0
2       1                   0               2
```

I have tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT SUM(Effort) AS JoeEffort, Min (Week) AS week FROM [Group$]
WHERE name = "Joe"
GROUP BY week
ORDER By week
```

which returned:

```
week   JoeEffort
1      3
2      1
```

and now I need the other columns and imagine in involves joins but am not sure how to complete the task

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Pivot/Self join? Did you try anything?

Comment: what if you have 1000's of names..?do you need a column with effort sum for each name?

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Amusingly, I notice the headers almost spell "weak effort".

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer here is the same:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you done to try to figure out your problem?

Comment: @vpk Sorry I should've specified that there are only a few unique names, but yes I desire one column per person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a PIVOT table would work, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        week,name,effort 
    FROM [Group$]
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(effort)
    FOR [name] IN ('quentin','joe','tracy')
)AS pvt
```